# "su doesn’t record the commands executed as root"

Tags: centos, root, command-history, su

I am currently reading book *Unix and Linux system administration - Evi Nemeth*.
On page 70 under the topic "su: substitute user identity" there is a statement that says **"su doesn’t record the commands executed as root, but it does create a log entry that states who became root and when."**
I am confused as I do *su root* on CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 and run the *history* command, I am able to see the command I ran as root.

P.S. [Added link of the book - older version.](https://books.google.com/books?id=GB_O89fnz_sC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=su%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20record%20the%20commands%20executed%20as%20root,%20but%20it%20does%20create%20a%20log%20entry%20that%20states%20who%20became%20root%20and%20when.&source=bl&ots=wK04K6ETgp&sig=ACfU3U2cZzQdgvKVKIcmvpbALqY_oBM_HQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjc8_T_1OTiAhUQ16wKHe9jDioQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=su%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20record%20the%20commands%20executed%20as%20root%2C%20but%20it%20does%20create%20a%20log%20entry%20that%20states%20who%20became%20root%20and%20when.&f=false)

Comment: Your shell is recording that, not `su`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history` only shows the commands that have been executed in the current shell. That history has a number of drawbacks:

1. it might not be stored to any file if the user configures the shell not to do that;
2. even if it's recorded, it's in a file that is write-accessible by the user (usually ~/.history, ~/.bash_history, ~/.zsh_history or something like that). Thus, it can be forged by the user.

All in all, it's not a trail that can be relied upon for security audit.

What the books means by "recording commands" is writing them into some log that is *not* accessible to the ordinary user. The book says that `su` *does* record something, so let's try it:

```
$ su
Password: 
root@firefly:/home/minoru# echo hello
hello
root@firefly:/home/minoru# exit
```

Now let's see what got recorded in `auth.log` (the path should be the same for most distros):

```
$ sudo less /var/log/auth.log
Jun 12 22:40:35 firefly su: (to root) minoru on pts/8
Jun 12 22:40:35 firefly su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Jun 12 22:40:41 firefly su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
```

We can see that I (minoru) got superuser privileges, and we can see *when* I did that, but there's no trace of `echo hello` I executed.

Now let's compare that to another tool, `sudo`, which is described in the next section of the book:

```
$ sudo echo hello
hello
$ sudo less /var/log/auth.log
Jun 12 22:44:48 firefly sudo:   minoru : TTY=pts/8 ; PWD=/home/minoru ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/echo hello
Jun 12 22:44:48 firefly sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 12 22:44:48 firefly sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Again we see who got the privileges and when, but we also see which directory I was in at the time (/var/log), what command I ran, and even what console I used. Much better!

Answer (score 1):

What you see using `history` is recorded by the shell, not by `su`. `su` itself doesn’t record the commands that are run as root. The author might have wanted to contrast this with `sudo` which does log its arguments (and can even be configured to record entire sessions).

Answer (score 0):

Recording normally means storing event info in the standard location at `/var/log`. There are plenty of other ways an activity leaves a trace otherwise, but those are not what she means here apparently. You can get more details in the same book in the chapter on logging (page 572 in the 5th edition).